# JQuery: multiple switch statements cancelling eachother out

Tags: jquery, switch-statement, case

Having some trouble with more than one switch statement at a time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').children('span').click(function(){
        whichsub = $(this).attr('id');
        switch (whichsub)   {
            case 'menu1':
            $('#submenu').load('menus/submenu1.html');
            break;
            case 'menu2':
            $('#submenu').load('menus/submenu2.html');
            break;
        };
        if ( $('#submenu').css('left') !== '150px' ) {$('#submenu').animate({left: '150px'}, 300);}
    });
    $('#submenu').children('span').click(function(){
        var whichcon = $(this).attr('id');
        switch (whichcon)   {
            case 'submenu1':
            $('#demopanel').load('content/profile.html');
            break;
            case 'submenu2':
            $('#demopanel').load('content/portfolio.html');
            break;
        };
        if ( $('#demopanel').css('marginLeft') !== '300px' ) {$('#demopanel').animate({marginLeft: '300px'}, 1000);}
    });
});
```

The top switch changes the submenu and conditionally slides it out, the bottom changes the content ("#demopanel"). Each works on it's own, but when I have both enabled, the second fails to work -- it acts as if the script has stopped since an alert placed after `$('#submenu').children('span').click(function(){` returns nothing.

Any ideas where this might be going wrong? Do I need to unbind something?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your HTMl structure? Since you are using the of children selector element, perhaps you are selecting the "menu" items twice. Causing our first click event to be over ridden by the second.

Comment: No, #menu and #submenu are siblings with all unique child ids. Think it's the repeated $(this) causing problems?

Comment: No, the "this" should be fine.Going along with the same thought as Bipen, if the submenu you're being loading by "$('#submenu').load('menus/submenu2.html');", then your  "$('#submenu').children('span').click(function()" will be get registered and thus you must use the "on" event as Bipen stated.

Comment: Yeah I tried this (both iterations posted here) and it doesn't seem to make any difference. Thanks

Comment: OK I got it working now, thanks to everyone! The delegate tip was right on.

Comment: The recommended way to indicate that your question has been answered is to Accept the best answer : this adds to the reputation of the answerer as well as to yours ; but above all it takes your question from the list of unanswered to the list of answered questions. No need to write "solved" in the title.

Answer (score 0):

delegate the submenu click since looks like you are loading dynamic content there using `on`..

```
$('#submenu').on('click','span',function(){
  ...

})
```

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about on delegated events

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your submenu is being dynamically loaded and therefore must use a delegated event. Try this..

```
  $('body').on('click','#submenu span',function(){
  ...

})
```